# neo4j or neo4j+mysql for partial graph dataset

Tags: mysql, neo4j

Even though I read another question here advising not to use both neo4j and mysql ([neo4j - graph database along with a relational database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11310229/neo4j-graph-database-along-with-a-relational-database)), I was wondering what approach would be the best for dataset that has some data which can be modeled like a graph and the rest looks relational. For some reasons, I can't post the kind of data I'm using.

I can shoehorn the relational part into neo4j but it looks ugly and complex, something I would want to avoid.

On the other hand, if I use both together, I'll have to do double the amount of queries to get the result, decreasing performance (assume the DBs are on cloud in separate machines).

I can't use mysql alone because one of the queries requires a depth of around 20-30 which I assume can't be handled by mysql.

Have any of you encountered such a situation before ? If so, how did you solve it ?

Comment: Two dbs sounds like a nightmare.  Could you refactor the relational stiff to work in a neo4j like manner?  I'm not talking graph like, I'm talking document centric like other nosql databases, for example mongo.  Neo4j works almost the same way but with graph functionality on top.

Comment: Good news is I haven't started yet, so don't need any refactoring :). How does mongo compare to neo4j for graph functionality ? Specifically, will it be well suited for DFS unto 30 nodes ?

Comment: Mongo doesn't have any graph functionality.  I was trying to say that you can do everything you can do in mongo in neo4j if that's what you need to do.  (store documents and index their fields).  By that I mean if you can refactor your relational store to a document store you're good do go.  You can do relations in document stores.

Comment: This talks about modeling one-many relationships in mongo but could equally apply to neo4j.  http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/model-embedded-one-to-many-relationships-between-documents/ (there's articles for other relationship types there)

Comment: Great, but performance is a high priority for this project as well as ease of programming/use. From, what you said, it sounds like I'll have to build the "graph functionality" part myself, no ?

Comment: Ok, let me look into it

Comment: What is the particular aspect where you would worry about performance? I agree that 'double queries' feels bad, but its honestly a bit fuzzy to me why it does. Already within SQL it seems most analysis ends up being done on views or cubes or other abstractions from the basic schema, which require the same time tolerance, either when preparing and designing or when consuming. I've been thinking a lot about your question myself and I find it hard to pinpoint what exactly I'm worried about for performance.

Comment: @user2103008 I'm not suggesting you use mongo.  I'm suggesting you use neo like a document store for the relational parts.

Comment: @jjaderberg You mean performance for using mysql + neo4j ? Well, they reside on different machines (although on the same cloud), which means network bandwidth/latency comes into picture for double queries (in addition to those b/w server and client), no ?.

Comment: Quite possibly network is a bottle neck, perhaps it depends on the 'logical proximity' of the end consumer to the databases. If consumer more or less queries DB directly it seems this problem grows, but if what is to be consumed is not rows in tables (or graph equivalents) but some abstraction or manipulation, then maybe not. For our use case putting semantics in Neo4j and data in MySQL, Cassandra et alia seems viable, but likely what will be consumed is an abstraction of these and other sources. These comment fields are too small; good question, look forward to hearing others' pronouncements.

Comment: As to frameworks, if Java and Spring is an option, convenience of design may possibly be had with [Spring Data](http://projects.spring.io/spring-data/) cross store persistence.

Comment: @tom:modeling that might be a mess. In essence, I would have multiple edges between two nodes, different kinds of nodes/edges etc and for queries where mysql performance is good, I'd be losing advantage. You can check mysql vs neo4j performance in this paper: http://www.cs.olemiss.edu/~ychen/publications/conference/vicknair_acmse10.pdf

Comment: I think you will have to tell us far more about your data before we can advise you properly.  That said, mapping SQL like relational data structures to a graph database isn't too hard ime.  Simplifying a bit here but one to one?  That's a relation.  One to many?  that's *many* relations.  Use indexes to look up documents and get relations from there, job done.

Answer (score 1):

As everyone else says: "give us a better idea of what data you are trying to model so we can best give you a suggestion".

That being said, dealing with 2 DBs is not an issue and its more common than people think: often-times you use a Full-Text store for searches and then get back a list of Document IDs which you then hit the relational DB for additional metadata. Or hitting Redis to get a list of IDs which you also hit the relational DB for more data.

I proof-of-concepted a system of Neo4j+MySQL for targeted searching based on your social network ("show me all restaurants my network has recommended ordered by depth (e.g. 1st level friend recs are weighted higher than 2nd level, and so on) and it didn't feel awkward. But I also didn't take it to scale.

You will be having to keep both datastores in sync. So in my case when a user recommends a place on the web app (which inserts it into MySQL) you then need to turn around and do the same insert into Neo. You probably want to do this asynchronously as well, so you'll need to setup a message queue with workers.

Comment: "You probably want to do this asynchronously as well". Node.js is good for it, no ?

Comment: @user2103008 maybe, but not necessarily.